# Change header only in one page

Tags: header-footer, memoir

I'm starting the report of my capstone project.

I'm using the memoir package, taking [this template](https://github.com/willb/wi-thesis-template) as a reference Right now, I'm working in the formatting required by my college.

My problem is that there is a special page for the calification. The header of this page consists of the logo of my college at the left, followed by its name in upper case.

I have tried to include the following code in the file preamble.tex

```
%%Calification pagestyle
\makepagestyle{calification}
\makeheadrule{calification}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makeevenhead{calification}{\uppercase{\@collegename}}{}{}
\makeoddhead{calification}{\uppercase{\@collegename}}{}{}
\makeevenfoot{calification}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{calification}{}{}{}
```

Then, in thesisdefs.tex I define

```
\def\calification{
  \newpage
  \null\vfil
  \clearpage
  \makepagestyle{calification} 
}
\def\endcalification{\par\vfil\newpage}
```

And finally, at the beggining of frontmatter.tex

```
% CALIFICATION
\begin{calification}
Hello
\end{calification}
```

But it does nothing. I have the same header that in the rest of the front matter i.e. roman numerals on the top right corner.

Any idea on how to change the header only in one page? Right now I am only trying to put the name of the college there, will I have any problem if I try to include an image in the header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `\makepagestyle{calification}` to `\pagestyle{calification}` in your definition of `\calification`:

```
\def\calification{
  \newpage
  \null\vfil
  \clearpage
  \pagestyle{calification} 
}
\def\endcalification{\par\vfil\newpage}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm really surprised I was so close to the correct answer, because it is the first time I try to change the format of a document at this level.

In case it is helpful for anyone, this is my final solution:

```
%%Calification pagestyle
\makepagestyle{calification}
\makeoddhead{calification}{\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(5,0){\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{./includes/logoheader.png}}\end{picture}}{{\small Tex University}}{}
\makeoddhead{calification}{\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(5,0){\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{./includes/logoheader.png}}\end{picture}}{{\small Tex University}}{}
\makeevenfoot{calification}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{calification}{}{}{}
```

I wasn't able to use \@collegename (although it was defined). I got an error, so finally I just wrote it directly into the definition.

I also included the image. At first it messed all the page and the text was mixed with the header. My final solution is on the above code. I don't really understand what it does (I found this solution in another site), but it works!

Comment: did you remember the required `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` when dealing with macros with `@` in their name