# How to change header-footer only on a single page

Tags: header-footer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change header only in one page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66769/change-header-only-in-one-page)

I am trying to change the position of the header and footer only on a single page, because I want to make it landscape and I want to keep my current header-footer.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! The following link provides some possible solutions http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66769/19384

Comment: If using `fancyhdr`, you can define a `pagestyle`, say `mystyle` then in the page of concern, write `\thispagestyle{mystyle}` See for instance, this list of questions: http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=fancyhdr

Comment: Is the problem resolved? Please let us know- if so, we'll close it as a duplicate, if not please tell us how it is different :)

Comment: Yes the problem is resolved. Thanks for your help!