# how to use fancyhdr package to customize headers in landscape page

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, landscape, pdflscape

I have used the `fancyhdr` package to customize the header of my pages. However, when I want a page to be landscape (by using the `pdflscape` package), it does produce a page in landscape orientation, but the header is on the right side of the page (see attached picture). I am using the `article` document class. Here is my code:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection.\ #1}{}}
\lhead{\leftmark} %section 
\rhead{\thepage} %page number


\newpage
\begin{landscape}
\subsection{asdasd}
\end{landscape}
```

How can I move the header to the top of the page?

[image: this is the result which make me sad]

@grimler solved the problem with rotation of the header but now the pictures cannot be in the center and the margines of the landscape page is not symmetric

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}               
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, bottom=2cm, top=3cm]{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper} 

\begin{document}

\section{Nima}
\subsection{aaaaaaaaaaaaa}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{male.jpg}
  \caption{Example of a forward looking algorithm that identifies peaks \&     troughs.}
  \label{fig:old_zig_1}
\end{figure}


\newpage


\paperwidth=\pdfpageheight
\paperheight=\pdfpagewidth
\pdfpageheight=\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
\headwidth=\textheight



\begingroup 
\vsize=\textwidth
\hsize=\textheight


\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{male.jpg}
\end{center}
  \caption{Example of a forward looking algorithm that identifies peaks \& troughs.}
  \label{fig:old_zig_1}

\end{figure}

\endgroup
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Fancyhdr won't do it.  You have to turn off the current headers/footers and create custom versions.  See  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66769/change-header-only-in-one-page  and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226678/how-can-i-maintain-the-current-page-nodes-for-portrait-when-temporarily-entering/227229?s=15|0.0000#227229

Comment: It seems like the figure environment doesn't recognize the new margins and adjusts the graphics to the old textwidth. If you remove the figure environment and just write `\begin{center}\includegraphics[]{male.jpg}\end{center}` then centering works fine. (But you don't get a caption and label). The reason for the asymmetric margins is your `\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, bottom=2cm, top=3cm]{geometry}` line. We have tilted the page and this makes the right margin 1 cm longer than the other margins. To fix it, add `\addtolength{\textheight}{1cm}` before the `\headwidth=\textheight` line.

Comment: @Grimler Thank you so much , problems are all solved with the above comment.

Comment: For those using the ```\addtolength{\textheight}{1cm}``` line, be sure to ```\addtolength{\textheight}{-1cm}``` afterwards, else you get a blank page when going back to portrait mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Same question as [keeping-header-on-top-in-landscape-mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226324/keeping-header-on-top-in-landscape-mode)?

@touhami provided an excellent answer. Instead of using the landscape environment, change the geometry to landscape using:

```
\paperwidth=\pdfpageheight
\paperheight=\pdfpagewidth
\pdfpageheight=\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
```

and then set the headwidth to the textheight:

```
\headwidth=\textheight
```

Now set the textwidth & textheight locally within a group and write your landscape stuff:

```
\begingroup 
\vsize=\textwidth
\hsize=\textheight
%landscape stuff
\endgroup
```

and then change back to portrait using the same code (with the difference that the headwidth should be the textwidth).

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\paperwidth=\pdfpageheight
\paperheight=\pdfpagewidth
\pdfpageheight=\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
\headwidth=\textheight
\begingroup 
\vsize=\textwidth
\hsize=\textheight
\lipsum[2]
\endgroup
\newpage
\paperwidth=\pdfpageheight
\paperheight=\pdfpagewidth
\pdfpageheight=\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
\headwidth=\textwidth

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but it produces some problems with images. i cannot have the image in the center by using \centering.

Comment: @Nimakhin You're right. Didn't work for me either. 

    \begin{center}
    ...
    \end{center}

Works however, same for you?

Comment: No, it did not move the picture to the center !

Comment: Moreover, the margins in the landscape does not seem symmetric, how can i manage to have a symmetric margins in the landscape view?

Comment: @Nimakhin Could you provide a new MWE with these problems?

Comment: I have edited the question with the new MWE