# Using Titleps package to put header on a landscape page

Tags: header-footer, landscape, titleps

I used fancyhdr and the solution of the [how to use fancyhdr package to customize headers in landscape page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244955/how-to-use-fancyhdr-package-to-customize-headers-in-landscape-page?noredirect=1#comment582538_244955) post to create header on the top of landscape page. but i got familiar with Titleps package and i want to try that but again pdflscape did not work (the attached image)

[image]

insted of pdflscape, I used the solution of that post but i got following error:

```
LaTeX Warning: No \author given.

[1{e:/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./untitled-2.toc) [1] <pic/male.jpg, id=15, 265.99374pt x 265.99374pt>
<use pic/male.jpg> [1 <./pic/male.jpg>]
! Undefined control sequence.
l.75 \headwidth
           =\textheight
```

i used the following MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}               
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, bottom=2cm, top=3cm]{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper} 

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float} %place image here
\usepackage{pdflscape,lipsum} %landscape page
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{pdfpages,titleps}
\usepackage[pdfpagelabels,draft,implicit=false]{hyperref}




\newpagestyle{main}{%
  \setheadrule{0.5pt}%
  \sethead{\thesection~\sectiontitle}                      % header left
    {}                                                    % header center
    {\thesubsection~\subsectiontitle\quad$|$\quad\thepage}% header right
}
\pagestyle{main}




\begin{document}


\newpage

\paperwidth=\pdfpageheight
\paperheight=\pdfpagewidth
\pdfpageheight=\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
\addtolength{\textheight}{1cm}
\headwidth=\textheight

\begingroup 
\vsize=\textwidth
\hsize=\textheight


\lipsum[1]

\endgroup

\end{document}
```

I really appreciate any help

Comment: Headwidth is used by fancyhdr only, if you don't want to use fancyhdr, you can remove that line. There's probably a similar command with the titleps package that you can use to specify the width of the header

Comment: @Grimler thanks i used `\widenhead*{0pt}{15pc}` and the 15 was experimental :) and after that i used `\widenhead*{0pt}{0pc}` to reset everything.  everything is fine. tnx

Comment: Can you extend your MWE with your solution and post it as an answer? It is easier for others to find it and take advantage.

Comment: Is there any news here?

Answer (score 1):

The OP found that using `\widenhead` was a work around.  To get the correct parameters just use the values of `\textheight` and `\textwidth` as follows:

```
\widenhead*{0pt}{\dimexpr\textheight-\textwidth}
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, bottom=2cm, top=3cm]{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float} %place image here
\usepackage{pdflscape,lipsum} %landscape page
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{pdfpages,titleps}
\usepackage[pdfpagelabels,draft,implicit=false]{hyperref}

\newpagestyle{main}{%
  \setheadrule{0.5pt}%
  \sethead{\thesection~\sectiontitle}                      % header left
    {}                                                    % header center
    {\thesubsection~\subsectiontitle\quad$|$\quad\thepage}% header right
}
\pagestyle{main}




\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\clearpage

\paperwidth=\pdfpageheight
\paperheight=\pdfpagewidth
\pdfpageheight=\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
\addtolength{\textheight}{1cm}

\widenhead*{0pt}{\dimexpr\textheight-\textwidth}
\begingroup
\vsize=\textwidth
\hsize=\textheight

\lipsum[1]

\endgroup

\clearpage
\paperwidth=\pdfpageheight
\paperheight=\pdfpagewidth
\pdfpageheight=\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
\addtolength{\textheight}{-1cm}

\widenhead*{0pc}{0pc}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```