# How to use fancyhdr to customize headers for multiple landscape pages

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, double-sided, landscape

I have used this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244955/how-to-use-fancyhdr-package-to-customize-headers-in-landscape-page) to include two pdfs in landscape format. It works good for one page but not for two. This is my example:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}
Some text...
\newpage
\paperwidth=\pdfpageheight
\paperheight=\pdfpagewidth
\pdfpageheight=\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
\headwidth=\textheight
\section{New Section}
\begingroup 
\vsize=\textwidth
\hsize=\textheight
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=1.3\textwidth,page=1]{bla.pdf} 
\end{center}
\newpage
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=1.3\textwidth,page=2]{bla.pdf}
\end{center}
\endgroup
\newpage
\paperwidth=\pdfpageheight
\paperheight=\pdfpagewidth
\pdfpageheight=\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
\headwidth=\textwidth
Some Text...
\end{document}
```

My problem is that I'm using a twosided documentclass and the header is shifted to the left on even numbered pages. In addition I don't get pagenumbers in the footer on landscape pages.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don´t want to use `geometry`-package for this?

Comment: You should not use `fancyhdr` with `scrartcl`, you get respective warnings in the log-file.

Comment: [How to translate and rotate the heading of landscaped pages?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250998)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a KOMA-Script class you can use

```
\clearpage
\storeareas\mysavedlayout
\KOMAoptions{paper=landscape,headinclude}\recalctypearea
  landscape stuff ...
\clearpage
\mysavedlayout
```

to switch to landscape locally. To get the header right use `scrlayer-scrpage` (sets page style `scrheadings` by default) instead `fancyhdr`:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[markcase=upper,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[section]{section}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
Some text ...

\clearpage
\storeareas\mysavedlayout
\KOMAoptions{paper=landscape,headinclude}\recalctypearea
\section{New Section}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,page=1]{bla.pdf} 
\end{center}
\newpage
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,page=2]{bla.pdf}
\end{center}
\clearpage
\mysavedlayout

Some Text...
\end{document}
```

[image]