# Centering the figure caption when switching page orientation

Tags: horizontal-alignment, positioning, subfloats, r

I'm a newcomer to Latex but I've already found it very useful. I have a document that requires me to switch the orientation from portrait to landscape midway through the document so I can properly fit an image. I searched quite a few posts and was able to achieve it by doing the following in RMarkdown

```
\newpage
\paperwidth=\pdfpageheight
\paperheight=\pdfpagewidth
\pdfpageheight=\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
\headwidth=\textheight
\begingroup 
\vsize=\textwidth
\hsize=\textheight
```

Once I flipped the orientation I could insert my code for the figure

````
```{r, fig.pos = "H",fig.align='center', fig.cap="P3b Amplitude Fz (E15)", echo=FALSE, out.height='550px', out.width='600px', dpi=300}
knitr::include_graphics("images/P3bAmp_E15.png")
```
````

And then flip the page orientation back to portrait.

```
\endgroup

\newpage
\paperwidth=\pdfpageheight
\paperheight=\pdfpagewidth
\pdfpageheight=\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
\headwidth=\textwidth
```

I have 2 issues that I am currently running into. The first is that the caption will not center according to the width of a landscape page. Below are screenshots

[image: Portrait Orientation]

[image: Landscape Orientation]

Does anyone have any input on how this may be fixed?

Here is the header I have for the document in case it might be of use

````
---
title: "Data Report"
author: "My Name Here"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: yes
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 3
header-includes: 
      - \usepackage{pdflscape}
      - \usepackage{graphicx}
      - \usepackage{lipsum}
      - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
      - \usepackage{float}
      - \pagestyle{fancy}
      - \fancyhf{}
      - \fancyhead[C]{Header}
      - \fancyfoot[RO,RE]{\thepage}
---

```{r global_options, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.pos = 'H')
```
````

Comment: you would need to reset some more lengths but it is best not to use such low level setting, either use the `rotating` package and use `sidewaysfigure` instead of `figure` or use `lscape` package and use `\begin{landscape}.\begin{figure}...\end[landscape}`

Comment: Also note pdflscape, which cause landscape pages to appear upright.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I used this setting as it was described in a post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244955/how-to-use-fancyhdr-package-to-customize-headers-in-landscape-page).

If I use the suggestions you recommend.  I lose the rotations of my headers [img]https://i.imgur.com/Mo3vyKH.png[/img]